# modelling domain entity and relationship between them

Tags: c#, entity, domain-driven-design

Can someone help me model domain entities and relationships between them. When a contract is created it will always have a sow. sow will have a list of resources. A resource has start date, end date, name, hourly rate (dollars per hour). contract can have list of PCRs (project change request - null to many like pcr01,pcr02 etc). Each PCR have a list of resources. Resources in pcr can be a replacement for a resource in sow or previous pcr or a completely new resource or removal of resource from sow or previous pcr. Can someone help me come up with good entity modeling and database design. What I have done:

```
public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public String ResourceName { get; set; }
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public ChangeRequesttype ChangeRequesttype { get; set; }
    public Resource ReplacementFor { get; set; }
}

 public class Contract
{
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public string ContractName { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> Sow { get; set; }
    public List<Pcr> Pcrs { get; set; }
}
 public enum ChangeRequesttype
 {
    New = 1,
    Replacement = 2,
    Removal = 3
 }
```

Comment: Hi, your description doesn't match the code you've posted.  Can you look over both and edit them so that they match?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question DDD but you're talking about data structures. Are you sure you want DDD and not CRUD?

[Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) might help.